# Problem compiling with truffle, stuck on importing openzeppelin

Tags: compiler-errors, solidity, truffle, openzeppelin

I'm doing a tutorial on blockgeeks and have been stuck for hours.

This is the error i get when trying to compile my project

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC721\ERC721.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC721\IERC721.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC721\IERC721Receiver.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC721\extensions\IERC721Metadata.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\utils\Address.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\utils\Context.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\utils\Strings.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\utils\introspection\ERC165.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\utils\introspection\IERC165.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\virus.sol

ParserError: Expected string literal (path), "*" or alias list.
 --> /C/Users/Admin/virus/contracts/virus.sol:2:8:
  |
2 | import '@openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC721\ERC721.sol';
  |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Compilation failed. See above.
```

This is the code for my solidity file.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import ""@openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC721\ERC721.sol";

contract Virus is ERC721 {
  constructor() public ERC721("CryptoVirus", "Virus") {

  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am driving myself crazy with this. I have uninstalled and reinstalled truffle and openzeppelin and still no joy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your `import` statememnt.

```
import ""@openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC721\ERC721.sol";
```

opens with two quote signs `""`. Replace it to just one `"`

```
import "@openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC721\ERC721.sol";
```

Comment: Sorry that was a silly mistake I managed to include just before I copied over. I've tried many times with the correct quotes and no joy.